# Cast from specialized type to its generic interface

Tags: c#, generics

Generic type Covariance and Contravariance is all clear as long as we talk about animals and fishes, but why shouldn't this work, can you explain to me?

```
interface IType
{}

interface IGenericInterface<TType> where TType:IType
{}

class TypeImpl:IType
{}

class GenericTypeImpl : IGenericInterface<TypeImpl>
{}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Convert<IGenericInterface<TypeImpl>, TypeImpl>(new GenericTypeImpl());
    }

    static IGenericInterface<IType> Convert<S, D> (S instance) where S:IGenericInterface<D> where D:IType
    {
        return (IGenericInterface<IType>)instance; //nope
    }
}
```

indeed I can use out to solve the cast, but then I cannot do this:

```
interface IGenericInterface<out TType> where TType:IType
    {
        void afunction(TType type); //nope
        void afunction(IType type); //works but not nice
    }
```

Edit: there is no workaround for it. The reason I was interested (before giving up) is that I want to collect all the `GenericTypeImpl` instances in to a collection to be then used after through a generic function. Obviously the only way to store in a collection different implementation of `IGenericInterface<IType>` where IType implementation can vary, is to use `IGenericInterface<IType>` as collection parameter, so I needed to cast the single instance back to the original type and call the method `afunction`, with a code similar to this:

```
void CallSuitableAFunction<T>(T type) where T : IType
{
    if (_collectedInstances.TryGetValue(typeof(T), out instance))
    {
         (instance as IGenericInterface<T>).afunction(); //will throw
    }
}

Dictionary<Type, IGenericInterface<IType>> _collectedInstances;
```

Comment: Do you even need the cast? The type signature looks like the cast would be redundant?

Comment: sorry I need to add another part of code, I am stupid

Comment: you could avoid casting by making the collection itself generic. for example `Dictionary<Type, T>` where `T` is the generic type. you would need separate collections though.

Comment: T can differ, that's the all point. I can have several GenericTypeImplX that implement several IGenericInterface<TypeImplX>

Answer (score 2):

there is no Covariance nither Contravariance in your type implementations. you should use `out` for covariance (which is your case), or `in` for contravariance.

```
interface IGenericInterface<out TType> where TType:IType // notice out keyword
{}
```

when you make `TType` Covariance it should only be used as output, for example only in return type of method like `TType Method()` <s>or as out only argument `void Method(out TType)`</s>, this method `void Method(TType)` has input of `TType` so it is not compatible with covariance because of the rules (compiler rules are basically for type safety).

You can fix this issue by implementing another interface which does not contain that method, you will loose access to that method from that interface how ever (you need to cast).

```
interface IGenericInterfaceCovariant<out TType> where TType:IType
{
    // don't use TType as input        
    void afunction(IType type); // `IType` is still valid though since its interface. notice the "I" and "T" differences before "Type"
}
interface IGenericInterface<TType> : IGenericInterfaceCovariant<TType> where TType:IType
{ 
   void afunction(TType type);
}
```

then you can cast like this.

```
return (IGenericInterfaceCovariant<IType>)instance;
```

Comment: there is a problem with that, I will add in the question. Meanwhile could you explain to me why with out should work? The theory behind it I mean.

Comment: because you are using `TType` in input arguments. `out` is not compatible with `in` and vice verca. when you make `TType` Covariance it should only be used as output, for example only in return type of method like `TType Method()` or `void Method(out TType)`, note that `void Method(TType)` does not work

Comment: isn't there a solution that could allow me to use TType as function parameter of the interface?

Comment: see the update. there is not much you can do, either try to avoid casting by changing design or see if my solution is helpful @sebas

Comment: sounds promising, I will be back once I try it! Thanks!

Comment: it seems there isn't any workaround, my problem is that from the casted type I want to use afunction(TType) and not afunction(IType)

Comment: it was a typo. you can have `afunction(TType)` only in `IGenericInterface<TType>` and not in `IGenericInterfaceCovariant<out TType` but you can have this `void afunction(IType type)` in  `IGenericInterfaceCovariant<out TType` (notice the I and T differences.) @sebas

Comment: yes I guessed it was a typo, but after if I cast to (IGenericInterfaceCovariant<IType>) I can't use that function. I need to use the function after the cast. I think I had this problem in the past already and I am pretty sure I couldn't find any work around :(

Comment: Thats what i said at end of answer. You loose access to that function (you need to cast back). Or You should think about changing design or find way to avoid cast

Comment: basically the limitation I find is that I want a way to save a collection of different IGenericInterface<T> objects and use them back later again. Even if I am sure that the safety is guaranteed, c# doesn't allow me to do it. They must have their own reasons :)

Comment: @sebas: _"Even if I am sure that the safety is guaranteed, c# doesn't allow me to do it"_ -- that is simply not the case. Unfortunately, your question doesn't include a good enough [mcve] and explanation to understand why you think it is, but the compiler will _never_ 100% disallow safe operations. Indeed, the only place I'm even aware of where the basic behavior of the compiler is to disallow a safe cast is in a generic method, casting from a variable of `T` something more specialized, and even there you can get around the issue by casting to `object` first, to hide the original type.

Comment: the original code was the working example I used to ask my original question. I added some more info to explain why I needed the case working.